# How to create Multiple file picker/upload button in single HTML web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using google drive file picker in HTML web app, it's working perfectly fine with a single button, I am trying to add a 2nd button to upload the files and save in a different folder.

Please find my complete script in below sheet, please help me to fix or achieve the requirement

[Smaple Sheet with Code](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hjqqCDFE67aBWhckAQXNFM_jMRt-7mV0V2CT-J7TnsY/edit?usp=sharing) 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the same function name for picker 2. Change the function name so that app script can distinguish it.

In Code.gs change the change the 5th function name from `initPicker` to `initPicker2` and in javascript2.html make the below changes.

```
function openPicker2() {
  google.script.run
  .withFailureHandler(showMessage)
  .withSuccessHandler(showFilePicker)
  .initPicker2();
}

function openUploader2() {
  google.script.run
  .withFailureHandler(showMessage)
  .withSuccessHandler(showFileUploader)
  .initPicker2();
}
```

Comment: @ Ritz
Thanks Yes, able to upload the files

Answer (score 0):

In saving, try using [Save to Drive Button](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive).

As discussed in the documentation, include the necessary JavaScript resource and to add the Save to Drive button tag:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-savetodrive"
   data-src="//example.com/path/to/myfile.pdf"
   data-filename="My Statement.pdf"
   data-sitename="My Company Name">
</div>
```

With this, you can place multiple buttons per page which is implemented sequentially.

See [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/savetodrive#multiple_buttons_per_page) to learn more.